# The Fourier Series of a shifted, inverting delta function

Tags: fourier-series, signal-processing, fourier-transform

I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine the Fourier series for 
the following discrete function:

$$\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^m (\delta[n-2m] + \delta[n+3m]) .$$

Graphing it I understand that its periodic with $N = 12$ and $ \Omega_o = \frac{\pi}{6}$.

However I am having difficulty expanding the impulse functions into their complex representations. I know how the fourier series for a single simple impulse is 1 and for a time shifted impulse $$ \delta[n-p] $$ the general form is $$ e^{2\pi\Omega_op} X[k] $$ however in putting that together, also with the fact that the m variable on the delta is continually changing, I am having trouble getting my head around it.